# node.js code that works in Windows is not working on Mac

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

I have an app that uses Passport to login users through FB, Twitter and Google. It works fine on Windows. Now I had to move to Mac (Sierra).
The logins are not working. I get a "Error at Strategy.parseErrorResponse." 
Does anyone know what could be the reason?

```
// This is the Facebook strategy...
    =========================================================================
    // FACEBOOK ================================================================
    // =========================================================================
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

        clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)

    },
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function() {

            // check if the user is already logged in
            if (!req.user) {

                User.findOne({ 'facebook.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    if (user) {

                        // if there is a user id already but no token (user was linked at one point and then removed)
                        if (!user.facebook.token) {
                            user.facebook.token = token;
                            user.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                            // user.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                            user.save(function(err) {
                                if (err)
                                    throw err;
                                return done(null, user);
                            });
                        }

                        return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user, create them
                        var newUser            = new User();

                        newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id;
                        newUser.facebook.token = token;
                        newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                        // newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // user already exists and is logged in, we have to link accounts
                var user            = req.user; // pull the user out of the session

                user.facebook.id    = profile.id;
                user.facebook.token = token;
                user.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                // user.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, user);
                });

            }
        });

    }));
```

Comment: It is highly unlikely anyone can help you without seeing your code.  Questions about code should include the relevant portions of the code and exact error messages with the corresponding lines of code responsible for the errors.

Comment: Finally got it working. It had to do with dependency versions...

Comment: To close this issue, if you can explain what you did to fix it in a way that would help others in the future, then you can write your own answer to your question and eventually accept it.  Or, if it's not an issue you can describe that might help others, then you can just delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by changing the versions of the dependencies to latest versions.